# Is there a maximum number of calculations that can be performed by a program before it stops working?

Tags: c, codeblocks

My apologies for the general nature of this question, but I cannot think of a good way to word it... Put simply, I'm a beginner that's written a program (in C, using CodeBlocks-EP) that performs a very large number of calculations (for simplicity, I've replaced the real (very useful) code with a pointless loop that also has a large number of calculations!).

```
    int x, i;

    for (i=0; i<9999999999999999; i++){
        x=x+1;
        x=x-1;          //real code is much more useful but spans 3000 lines!
    }
    printf("x is %i", x);     //useful output
```

As I said, it works fine, and gives useful output. However, recently, I tried to make it run once for every day of a virtual year, rather than for just one day, like the following:

```
    int x, i, day;

    for (day=0; day<365; day++){
        for (i=0; i<9999999999999999; i++){
            x=x+1;
            x=x-1;         //real code is much more useful but spans 3000 lines!
        }
    }
    printf("x is %i", x);     //useful output
```

and I received the following message before I get useful output:

**My_program**.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available. Process terminated with status -1073741510 (24 seconds).

On further inspection, it stopped working around day 60. HOWEVER (and here's the weird part...), the program works if you choose a smaller period, e.g. for days 0-60, OR days 30-71, or days 60-101 (so it is NOT breaking because of a programming issue with day 61).

If I try to do more than around 60 days though (even days 0-70), it breaks after about 60 days. I can't think of anything wrong other than the fact that it is breaking due to "too many calculations"... But I've never heard of that problem. I'm a bit of a newbie, so any advice would be greatly appreciated here!

I appreciate that it is unhelpful to not have the actual code, but at 3000 lines, it seemed sensible to replace it with something simpler! But I can confirm that it works for each individual day of the year, when ran as separate individual days... Just not as a block! If I can help by providing any other information, please let me know.

Many thanks,

Matt

Update (23:21 26/12/2013): Thanks a lot for all the responses- turned out it was a memory leak and I'd missed a line of code resetting one of the counters, which in turn tried to then make a giant matrix... Sorry for being a noob and not knowing how to diagnose it, but I feel like I've learned something; thanks for the help!

Comment: `i` will cry for `9999999999999999`!

Comment: There is no "too many calculations" error. You're probably leaking memory somewhere.

Comment: I'm very worried that someone who is responsible for a 3K-line program doesn't know how to debug problems like this.

Comment: Which compiler/platform are you using please?

Comment: How many times does the word "assert" appear in the 3000 lines of actual code.

Comment: Some OS will complain if code _appears_ to be stuck in a rut.  One such detection depends upon a timely function call between chunks of code - which this double nested loop has none.  Try `for (day=0; day<365; day++){ SomeFunction(); for (i=0; i<999...`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a maximum number of calculations that can be performed by a program before it stops working?

No.  You probably have either a memory leak or a numeric overflow in your program that only shows up after 60 days of operation.

Comment: This could be caused by the default maximum stack size ( 1MB on Windows and 8MB on Linux).

Comment: You legend! Can't believe it was something so simple- had me stumped for hours, but it was indeed a memory leak; I'd missed a line of code resetting a counter on each loop. Cheers man! Updated problem, and I tried voting your answer as useful but I have no rep! Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 32-Bit System, you can loop only over numbers <= 32 Bit. If you have an 64Bit System you can only loop over numbers that are smaller or equal 64 Bit. If you have a number, that's greater than 32Bit or 64Bit you get an overflow. If you use something like `999999999999999999` it's to big for a 32 Bit register. Try `9999999999999999999L` and declare `i` as `long`.

Comment: If it's an "int", it may still only be 32 bits wide no matter how you write the constant. On a 32 bit machine, the largest "int" (signed) is 2147483647. If you need more loops than that, you'll have to nest them.

Comment: If you would read my answer, you would see that i said that he should declare `i` as `long`. And on a 64 Bit machine it works.

Comment: There very well exist C implementations for 32bit machines providing integers with 64bit width.

Comment: Yes could be, but if the compiler uses the ecx register (Count register) for the iteration variable, you can only use 32Bit Integers because it's only 32 Bit wide.

Comment: (0) The size of an `int` is determined by the C implementation, not by the architecture of the target system. A C implementation may have a 32-bit or 64-bit or other `int` on a 32-bit architecture and may have a 32-bit or 64-bit or other `int` on a 64-bit architecture. (1) `9999999999999999999` is automatically a type long enough to represent it; there is no need for suffixing it with an `L`. (2) “Fixing” the loop to give it 9999999999999999 iterations will not help; this will cause the program to run for some years in the inner loop before `day` is changed.

Comment: (3) Reasoning about the program behavior based on the `ecx` register is inappropriate. Even if the program is running on an Intel processor (where there is an `ecx` register), the semantics are determined by the C standard and the C implementation; the implementation is responsible for implementing the semantics regardless of whether the `ecx` register alone suffices. A 32-bit register does not limit `for` loops to 2**32 iterations, as the compiler may generate code that uses multiple steps to perform the necessary work.